# What is this technique called?

Tags: apex, apex-variable, lazy-loading

```
public static List<Holiday> holidays {
        get {
            if(holidays == null)
                holidays=[Select h.StartTimeInMinutes, h.Name, h.ActivityDate From Holiday h];
            return holidays;
        }
        private set;
    }
```

Reference links if possible.

Answer (score 8):

It's called **Lazy Loading** or **Lazy initialization**

> Lazy loading is a design pattern to defer initialization until the point at which it is needed.

Reference

- [Lazy Loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading)
- [Lazy initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization)

Answer (score 3):

Well its combination of few, As Robs mentioned its caled lazy loading. Also Its called as Singleton Pattern.

Singleton pattern makes sure, you have a single instance of a particular instancein the whole transaction(in your case holidays).

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Design_Patterns_-_Singleton

Comment: Singleton is generally used when you want a single instance of a class rather than a property value.